# Is there a way to have a container of derived classes where upon retrieval they are recognized as the derived class and not the base class?

Tags: c++

I want to have a container of objects from classes derived from the same base class. It seems the best way to do this is to have a container of pointers to the base class and point these to the derived class objects. However, I want to retrieve an object and pass it into a global function that is overloaded for the derived classes:

```
Class Base {};
Class A : public Base {};
Class B : public Base {};

double MyFunction(const A &a_object) {does things};
double MyFunction(const B &b_object) {does different things};

typedef boost::shared_ptr<Base> Ptr;
typedef std::vector<Ptr> PtrContainer;

int main()
{
    PtrContainer MagicContainer;

    //Fill MagicContainer with A's and B's



    double result = MyFunction(*MagicContiner[0]); //Compiler can't resolve
    //which MyFunction to use
}
```

I know if I made MyFunction a virtual member function of Base (resp. A, B) this would work, but I want to keep MyFunction global (or possibly in a separate class). I'm very new to C++, so any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you put the specialized behavior behind a virtual method?  Trying to couple non-method functions to classes like this is bad design, and will lead to poorly maintainable code.  You really want all the class-specific behaviors _in_ the class if you can.

Answer (score 1):

Add a virtual member function in `Base`, that is implemented differently for each derived class.

If doesn't feel right to have it in `Base`, perhaps add an intermediate class derived from `Base`, which `A` and `B` then derive from.

More generally the solution to such a problem is not to downcast at each caller site, but to centralize that downcasting in the classes themselves by way of the visitor pattern, but for the case at hand using visitor pattern seems like a too heavy-weight solution: just an ordinary virtual function will probably do.